# Replace Old image with new image in laravel

Tags: laravel, image, replace

**CONTROLLER**

```
       public function updateproduct(Request $request, $id)
   {
    //    dd($request->all());
            $request->validate([
            'name'=>'required',
            'description'=>'required',
            'price'=>'required|numeric',
            'quantity'=>'required|numeric',
        ]);
        $product = Product::where('id', $id)->first();
        if(is_null($product)) {
            $product = new Product();
        }    
        $product->name=$request->name;
        $product->description=$request->description;
        $product->price=$request->price;
        $product->quantity=$request->quantity;    
        
            if($request->hasfile('images')){
                $existingimages = Image::where(['product_id'=> $product->id, 'source'=> 1])->get();
                if($existingimages->count() > 0)
                    foreach($existingimages as $existingimage) { 
                        $filename = public_path().'files/'.$existingimage->name;
                        if(file_exists($filename)){
                        unlink($filename);
                        $existingimage->delete();
                    }
                    }
                foreach($request->file('images') as $file){
               $name = rand(1,9999).'.'.$file->getClientOriginalName().$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
               if($file->move(public_path().'/files/', $name)){
                $updateImage = Image::firstWhere('product_id', $product->id);
                $updateImage->images = $name;
                $updateImage->source = 1;
                $updateImage->save();
               }  
            }
            }
```

Please check updated question. Request you to correct me if I wrong. Right now it only updates 1 image and other images remains same. please help me with this.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? As far as I see, you are using `Image::create` - what makes you think that this updates anything?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is somewhat confusing, I'm afraid.

Your request appears to allow for multiple images to be uploaded. Here :

```
if(file_exists($imagePath)){
    unlink($imagePath);
}
```

you look like you're trying to delete any images that already exist, but when you store upload images you're assigning them a random name (which Laravel can already handle for you, by the way, so there's no need to do it yourself) so you're unlikely to be actually deleting them because there'll likely be no file at that location anyway.

Nowhere does your code actually delete any existing images from the database. Essentially what you want to do is :

1. If the upload has images, retrieve all the existing images for that product.
2. Delete the physical files for those existing images.
3. Delete the database entries for those existing images.
4. Upload your new images and save their details to the database.

Translating that into code means :

```
if($request->hasfile('images')){
    // Delete any existing image files and database entries.
    $existingimages = Image::where('product_id', $product->id)->get();
    if($existingimages->count() > 0)
        foreach($existingimages as $existingimage) { 
            $filename = public_path().'files/'.$existingimage->name;
            unlink($filename);
            $existingimage->delete();
        }
    }
    // Carry on with your upload
}
```

Comment: It gives this error. 
unlink(C:\xampp\htdocs\practical1\publicfiles/): No such file or directory

Comment: OK, well, you're mixing local with remote development, but : 

$filename = public_path().'files/'.$existingimage->name; should become $filename = public_path().'\files\'.$existingimage->name; and add in a check with "file_exists" first.

Comment: It is still not working.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check and guide me

Comment: There's no more guidance needed - you've been told why it's adding, not deleting / replacing images, and given pointers on the code to use to get to where you want. From here on it's down to you.

Answer (score 0):

It adds new images because you are using the `Image::create` method. If I understood correctly, you want to modify the images of your products in the image table.

Try to modify your code like :

```
$updateImage = Image::firstWhere('product_id', $product->id);
$updateImage->images = $name;
$updateImage->source = 1;
$updateImage->save();
```